# Can the salt-cloud EC2 provider use temporary credentials issued by AWS Security Token Service (STS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, salt-cloud

Reading through the salt-cloud docs it appears I can only provide an access key ID (via the 'id:' line) and a secret access key (via the 'key:' line).

I have tested this out using the access key id and secret access key issued by STS, but I always get a 'credentials not recognized' error.

Is there a way to configure salt-cloud to also use the session token that is returned by AWS STS along with the access and secret keys?

I am testing this using salt-cloud version 3005.1. Yes, I know this is an older version, but even the current docs don't reference STS or the session token.